# No resource method found for options, return OK with Allow header: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.DefaultOptionsMethodException

Tags: java, rest, ionic2, resteasy

I am trying to make a post request from my Ionic 3 application to a Java resource but it bursts that error that is in the title, below is the method for which I am making the request:

```
@POST
@Path("/loginCpf")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Integer validarBeneficiarioCpf(BeneficiarioLoginTO beneficiario) throws Exception, TypeWarnWebException {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession(true);
    Integer numOpcoes = beneficiarioLoginNegocio.validarCpfLogin(beneficiario);
    if(session.getAttribute("beneficiario") == null && numOpcoes == null){
        return -1;
    }
    return numOpcoes;
}
```

and the error that throws:

```
09:32:0 3,649 ERROR [br.gov.transportes.spl.web.exception.provider.ExceptionResourceMapper] (http--0.0.0.0-443-3) No resource method found for options, return OK with Allow header: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.DefaultOptionsMethodException: No resource method found for options, return OK with Allow header
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.Segment.match(Segment.java:107) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:33) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:327) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:44) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:327) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:374) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:367) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:307) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:173) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:118) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at br.gov.transportes.spl.web.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:36) [classes:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

This is my Ionic 2 request method:

```
  getUser() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const body = {
        'nrCpf': '00000000000',
        'dtNascimento': ''
      };

      let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });

      let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
      });

      this.http.post(this.API_URL, body, options)
          .subscribe((data: any) => {
            resolve(data);
          }, (err: any) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    }); 
  }
```

When I debug my application the request falls into this filter:

```
@WebFilter("*")
public class CacheFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String page = httpRequest.getRequestURI();


        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

        if (!page.contains("fontawesome-webfont.eot") && !page.contains("/js/lib/") && !page.contains("/css/")) {
            httpResponse.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
            httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        } else {
            httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + 604800);
            httpResponse.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", new Date().getTime());
        }
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

The error is thrown when the `chain.doFilter(request, response);` when I make the same requisition with postman the function works, but I make the requisition with the raw data and the content-type with application/json, in my Ionic application I have made the header content-tyoe application/json and thrown the same error.

Comment: could you change the line `httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST");` with `httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,OPTION,PUT,DELETE");`?

Comment: Yap, still the same :(

Comment: I've made a mistake: not `...,OPTION,...` but `...,OPTIONS,...` (with trailing `S`)

Comment: Even so, I had try this before. When I debug the application the error is thrown when come here `chain.doFilter(request, response);` and when I see what is on request and response var dont has nothing diferent of the postman requisition. This is drive me crazy

Answer (score 3):

Well the actual problem occurs because the JavaScript runtime performs a so called "preflight" request using the HTTP OPTIONS method in case of CORS. More details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS). If you don't provide an OPTIONS method in your server, this results in the described exception. Thus, you have 2 alternatives to solve this problem:

1. You create a method annotated with "@OPTIONS" in your REST service like this:

   ```
   @OPTIONS
   @Path("/loginCpf")
   public Response optionsBeneficiarioCpf() {
      return Response.ok().header(HttpHeaders.ALLOW, HttpMethod.POST).build();
   }
   ```
2. You handle the OPTIONS requests in a generic fashion, for instance within the CORS filter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077335/options-request-for-restful-cross-domain-using-cors).

Answer (score 2):

I finnaly find the answer, my Java backend was not prepared to receive requisitions of another resources so this happen. So I have made a Cors Filter to solve this issue.

this is the filter:

```
package yor.package.addres.goes.here;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

        // Just ACCEPT and REPLY OK if OPTIONS
      // TODO removing this if
        if ( request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```